# How to avoid subdirectory output in node-sass?

Tags: npm, sass, node-sass

I have following setup under my project:

- `/assets/scss` has many SCSS files organized under different subdirectories; including a root global.scss file. As you can imagine, global.scss will only have @imports.
- `/assets/css` is set as output directory. I am trying to output only one file under this folder - `global.css`.

package.json has this command

```
"scripts": {
    "scss": "node-sass --watch assets/scss/styleguide.scss -o assets/css --recursive"
  }
```

When I run `npm run scss` it outputs subdirectory CSS files as well. Does anyone know how to avoid output of subdirectory sass files?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are passing the `--recursive` argument to `node-sass`. That will mean that `node-sass` will search recursively on every directory under `assets/scss` and will compile all the `scss` files found. To avoid that behavior just remove the `--recursive` option:

```
"scripts": {
    "scss": "node-sass --watch assets/scss/styleguide.scss -o assets/css"
}
```

More about `node-sass` usages and options can be found [here](https://github.com/sass/node-sass).